# show menu when mouse at left of the screen Jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to show left side menu when mouse cursor is closer then 20px to the left of the screen. I want the menu to stay on when mouse over it.

this code doesnt work right for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lmenu").hide(300);
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if(e.pageX<20 || $("#lmenu").is(':hover')) $("#lmenu").show(200);//html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
        else if(!$("#lmenu").is(':hover')) setTimeout(function(){ $("#lmenu").hide(200); }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use code similar to the following:

```
var menu = $('.menu');
var menuTimeout = null;

$(window).on('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
    if (e.pageX < 20 || menu.is(':hover')) {
        // Show the menu if mouse is within 20 pixels
        // from the left or we are hovering over it
        clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
        menuTimeout = null;
        showMenu();
    } else if (menuTimeout === null) {
        // Hide the menu if the mouse is further than 20 pixels
        // from the left and it is not hovering over the menu
        // and we aren't already scheduled to hide it
        menuTimeout = setTimeout(hideMenu, 2000);
    }
}
```

It should be obvious what the functions `showMenu` and `hideMenu` do.

Here's a full [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdQNpd).

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to hide it after 2 secs.

Comment: You should state that in the question.

Comment: I've updated this to include a 2s timeout before hiding the menu.

Comment: it doesnt in IE8 I can see it it dissapears & never show up again

Comment: Well, I don't have time to debug it in IE at the moment. You can try debugging it, or someone else can.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that every time you move a mouse and the mouse is not over the menu or farther then 20 px from the right edge of the screen - a setTimeout is fired. All this Timeouts go into queue and fire at will afterwards. That's why you get the "blinking" effect.

Answer (score 0):

I got generally decent results doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lmenu").hide(300);
    $("#lmenu").mouseover(function(){
       $(this).data("hover",true); 
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeData("hover");
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        console.log(e.pageX);
        if ((e.pageX < 20 || $("#lmenu").data("hover")) && !$("#lmenu").data("displayed")) {
            window.clearTimeout(window.hideMenu);
            $("#lmenu").stop().show(200).data("displayed",true);
        } else if ($("#lmenu").data("displayed")) {
            window.clearTimeout(window.hideMenu);
            $("#lmenu").removeData("displayed");
            window.hideMenu = window.setTimeout(function(){
                $("#lmenu").stop().hide(200);
            },2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zXDB3/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<div id="menuHidden" class="menu"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#menuHidden{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:purple;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display:none;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).on("mousemove", function(e){
    if(e.pageX <= 100)
    {
        $("#menuHidden").show();
    }
    else
    {
        if(!$(e.target).is(".menu"))
        {
            $("#menuHidden").hide();   
        }
    }
});
```

How it looks:
http://jsfiddle.net/nnmMe/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use a element(transparent) and capture the hover event on it.

like this:

```
 <aside class="bar hover-me"></aside>
```

css

```
.bar {
        background-color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;  
        z-index: 1;
        width: 20px; 
    }
```

js

```
$('.hover-me').mouseover(function(){
    $("#lmenu").show();
});
$("#lmenu").mouseleave(function(){ $(this).hide(); })
```